# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin(x)(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos(x)})\;\mathrm dx$ with substitution?

Tags: integration

I have to calculate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin x \cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})\,\mathrm dx$$ using the substitution $u(x)=2-\cos x$.
What I got so far is:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin x\cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})\,\mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin x \cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{u})\,\mathrm dx$$
and with $u'=du/dx$ I get $dx=du/\sin x$, that makes:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos x+\sqrt{u})du$$
Now, integrating $\sqrt u$ isn't the problem, but how to deal with $\cos x$ when it says $du$ instead of $dx$?

Comment: $\cos(x)=2-u$, no?

Comment: Why didn't you make the substitution on the _other_ term which _is_ $ \ \cos x \ $ ?

Comment: Because the task says to do the substitution $u=2-cos x$ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want to try simple substitution:
[$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin x \cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})\,\mathrm dx=-\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})\,\mathrm d\cos(x)=0$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%20%5Cpi%20%7D%20%5Csin%20%28x%29%20%5Cleft%28%5Ccos%20%28x%29%2b%5Csqrt%7B2-%5Ccos%20%28x%29%7D%5Cright%29%20%5C,%20dx)
Because $\cos(0)=\cos(2\pi)=1$

Speaking about you derivations:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos x+\sqrt{u})du$$
And you assumed the substitution $u(x)=2-\cos(x)$, so $\cos(x)=2-u(x)$ and 
$$\int_{1}^{1} (2-u +\sqrt{u})du$$

Comment: $\cos(0)=\cos(2\pi)=1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee My bad. Copying LaTeX from Mathematica without checking can bring such ridiculous things. :)

Answer (score 1):

I love this question because the anti-derivative is very easy to find if you just use additivity.

$$\int \sin(x)\cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})\,dx=\int\sin x\cos x\,dx+\int\sin x\sqrt{2-\cos x}\,dx,$$
where the first integral needs a manipulation and we have the function-derivative pattern clear in the second... $u=2-\cos x.$

Answer (score 0):

I got this
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\cos x+\sqrt{u})\,\mathrm dx$$=$$\int_{1}^{1} (2-u+\sqrt{u})\,\mathrm du$$ using the substitution $2-u(x)=\cos x$.
and when $$ x=0 : u=1  ; x=2\pi : u=1$$

But the problem are the limits. When you change the integration variable, the limits also change; what does one do when the limits turn out to be the same?

Comment: The plot of $$\sin x \cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})$$ is periodic and resembles a sine curve. I presume that its integral over a whole period of $2\pi$ is 0. The definite integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin x \cdot(\cos x+\sqrt{2-\cos x})\,\mathrm dx$ is hence zero. But the problem of the same-limits still remains......

Comment: As @Sy123 says, the same-limit really seems wrong. Nice one about splitting the integral in two parts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the same limits arises because a change in variable can only be used if the function used is a 1-to-1 function among the range of values it must take. In this case, over the interval, $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$, the function, $2-\cos x$ is not monotonic.

Because of this, we need to split the integral into 2 integrals, i.e.:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x) (\cos(x) + \sqrt{2-\cos(x)}) \ dx = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x) (\cos(x) + \sqrt{2-\cos(x)}) \ dx + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sin(x) (\cos(x) + \sqrt{2-\cos(x)}) \ dx$

Now that we have split the integral, we can use the change in variable:

$u=2-\cos x$ since in each integral, the function used is monotonic in each integral.

Then follows the generic:

$du = \sin x \ dx $

$x=0 \rightarrow u= 1$

$x=\pi \rightarrow u= 3$

$x=2\pi \rightarrow u= 1$

Substituting it all in,

$I = \int_1^3 \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{2-u} \ du + \int_3^1 \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{2-u} = 0 $

This is because for the second integral we can flip the limits, and make the integral negative. By pure coincidence, we arrive at zero.

Since:

$\int_a^a f(x) \ dx = 0$

Which makes sense since it is finding the area of a 1-dimensional line, which has no area.

However I am pretty sure that simply substituting $u=2\cos x$ without splitting the integral is wrong, even though you arrive at the same answer.